# Why does this gives me an error (Multi Thread or ArrayList)?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have two threads which are running and I need to control if the bullet is touching the enemy but it gives me this problem where I printed "s4". Any idea what happened there? I'm quite a beginner. I'm using Java.

```
ArrayList<Nemico> nemici= o_orda.getNemici();
        for (Nemico nemico : nemici) {
            if(Collisioni.ControllaCollisioni(o_navicella, nemico)){
                nemici.remove(nemico);
                this.o_navicella.vita-=10;



                break;
            }
            for (Proiettile pro : proiettili){
                System.out.println("s1");
                    if(Collisioni.CollsioniProiettile(pro, nemico)){
                        System.out.println("s2");
                        nemici.remove(nemico);
                        System.out.println("s3");
                        proiettili.remove(pro);
                        System.out.println("s4");
                        break;

                }
                    System.out.println("s5");
            }

            if(ControllaSconfitta()){
                this.giocON=false;
                Disegna();
            }
        }
```

This is the code, I'm sure it will help you. 
This code is in a function that checks and update everything every n millisecond.

Thanks for the help

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and it freeze the game when the collsion happens.

Comment: check [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) and the *fail-fast* part (iterator, which is used in for-each loops) of [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: You should probably use a loop with a real iterator. You can then use the iterator to add or delete from the ArrayList.

Comment: Use getListIterator() for best results.

Comment: OK, can you an example on my code on how it should work the iterator? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*The below code has been updated to use Iterator.remove() instead of ArrayList.remove(). Thank you to @PeterRader for clarifying how these should be used.*

---

If you are intending to modify an ArrayList while iterating over it, you should not use a for-each loop to iterate over it directly. There are two alternative approaches, using an iterator to avoid iterating over the ArrayList itself, or using Java 8's removeIf() function.

I will give a simple (and tested) example of using an iterator, and then attempt to modify your code to do the same thing:

**Iterator Example**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class IteratorExample{

     public static void main(String []args){

        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));

        // Get an Iterator to iterate over the Integers in arrList

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = arrList.iterator();

        // While iterator hasNext element, access this element with .next() and print it. 
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }


     }
}
```

**Modifying your code to use an iterator**

Apologies for any spelling mistakes or syntax errors in this version - I have been unable to test it, but given it's only a small piece of code there shouldn't be many and hopefully you will be able to remedy them using the example above. **Don't forget to import java.util.Iterator too!**

```
ArrayList<Nemico> nemici= o_orda.getNemici();

Iterator<Nemico> nemiciIterator = nemici.iterator();

while (nemiciIterator.hasNext()) {

    nemico = nemiciIterator.next();

    if(Collisioni.ControllaCollisioni(o_navicella, nemico)){
        nemiciIterator.remove(nemico);
        this.o_navicella.vita-=10;
        break;
    }

    Iterator<Proiettile> proIterator = proiettili.iterator();

    while (proIterator.hasNext()) {

        pro = proIterator.next();

        if(Collisioni.CollsioniProiettile(pro, nemico)){
            nemiciIterator.remove(nemico);
            proIterator.remove(pro);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(ControllaSconfitta()){
        this.giocON=false;
        Disegna();
        }
    }
    ...
```

**Resources**

Here is a relevant resource. This also includes an example of using removeIf()! https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrentmodificationexception.

Comment: @PeterRader Thank you, though I’m not sure that that is correct. I don’t wish to remove the item from the iterator, I wish to remove it from the ArrayList itself (nemici), as the original poster was attempting to do. Iterator.next() removes the object from the iterator and returns it, so there is no need to explicitly remove it (I’m not even sure Iterator.remove() is a method). Removing objects from the iterator would still leave them in the initial ArrayList would it not? Could you provide some clarification?

Comment: @PeterRader Hi Peter, thank you very much for clarifying - I did not realise that this was the case. I have now updated the answer accordingly, hopefully this is now correct.

Comment: Tom at your service, great answer!